# Kendo-Vue Hide button in column?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm struggling with this one, i need to hide a button, i mean a command button based on the value of a column.

i grab the following example from kendo pages, i would like to show/hide the button "View Details" based on the "Discontinued" value.
i've already tested with :visible or :hide properties without success.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/e1fre3

does someone know how to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [command option](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/grid/api/GridColumn/#toc-command) is expecting string or array so this is an updated stackblitz example that worked at my side - https://stackblitz.com/edit/e1fre3-wnzfer?file=index.html